# Need to Hide one payment method on WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: css, wordpress

I have disabled credit card payment/ Infusionsoft gateway in WooCommerce settings, But it's still showing Credit Card payment option on Checkout. Now, I want to hide it till I find a permanent solution from Plugin guys. Can you please help me where I can put in "display:none" to hide second radio button on the page. Please see the screen shot. [See Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COBNA.jpg)

Comment: thats a very bad approach!

Answer (score 3):

```
function payment_gateway_disable_postpay( $available_gateways ) 
{    
    unset( $available_gateways['paytm'] ); //replace paytm with your payment gateway
    return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_postpay' );
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `display:none;` to the `payment_method_infusionsoft` class in your custom CSS.

The best way to do this is using a "Chain" selector like so:

```
li.wc_payment_method.payment_method_infusionsoft{
 display:none !important;
}
```

[More about css display property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)